# Can I use a credit card EMV chip as a client-side SSL Cert?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl-certificate

Is there a way to read the certificate in a consumer credit card EMV chip and use this to authenticate to an Apache web server using the client-side certificate support in SSL/TLS?

Comment: Now that's a creative idea. But unless you're the card issuer, people are very unlikely to be willing to authenticate with their credit cards.

Comment: Why do you say that?